# How do I shut down or reboot from a terminal?

Tags: command-line, shutdown, reboot

How can I shut down or reboot Ubuntu using terminal commands?

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [Shutting down the system using a virtual console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872462/shutting-down-the-system-using-a-virtual-console)

Answer (score 1196, accepted):

For shutdown:

```
sudo poweroff
```

For restart:

```
sudo reboot
```

Appendix:
If your keyboard is "locked up", so you can't enter a command like "reboot" which would run from "su" anyway, use the keyboard: hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen/SysRq</kbd>, buttons and type "REISUB".  It doesn't have to be capital letters.  It will restart your computer gently.  http://blog.kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/

Comment: `sudo` might not be needed, actually.

Comment: On Armbian, just `reboot` is not found. instead, `/sbin/reboot` works.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus It depends on your `PATH` variable, and your `SECURE_PATH` in the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: what about `shutdown now` and `shutdown -r now`?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul nopes, for me i see this without `sudo`.   `Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to reboot system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to open /dev/initctl: Permission denied
Failed to talk to init daemon.`

Comment: On both [there is no need for `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/a/787274/349837). [`shutdown`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/shutdown.8.html) will give you 1 minute. REI (from REISUB) is now disabled by default.

Answer (score 247):

Open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and do these following commands

To shutdown the system:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

To restart:

```
sudo reboot
```

& one more command for restart:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Another way as one of the user mentioned.

For shutdown:

```
sudo halt
```

or:

```
sudo init 0
```

For restart:

```
sudo init 6
```

You can get more info on the `shutdown` command by using one of the following:

- `shutdown --help`
- `man shutdown`

Comment: @jai the target is to offer the op and everyone else alternative ways of doing what he has asked.

Comment: It seems `shutdown -r now` is preferable to `reboot` as the second can put you into maintenance mode

Comment: FYI [What is the difference between the shutdown, halt and reboot commands?](http://superuser.com/q/236908/116475)

Comment: Can anyone explain why `sudo halt` might not perform shutdown in some cases, whereas `sudo halt -p` does?

Answer (score 103):

Hate passwords (`sudo`) and love one-liners?

### For Ubuntu 15.04 and later

This is due to Ubuntu's shift in using `systemd` instead of `Upstart`

```
systemctl poweroff
systemctl reboot
systemctl suspend
systemctl hibernate
systemctl hybrid-sleep
```

Since **hibernate** is normally disabled by default in Ubuntu systems, you can enable this by checking [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/617254/101985).

### For Ubuntu 14.10 or earlier

Shutdown:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

Restart:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart
```

**Other commands you may like:**

Suspend:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

Hibernate: (if enabled on your system)

```
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Hibernate
```

Comment: I always wondered how the GUI shutdown the system without needing sudo.  I assume this is it.

Comment: Today I found an advantage to `systemd`.

Comment: @systemd And what is that?!

Answer (score 44):

## On 16.04 no need of `sudo`

To [shutdown](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/shutdown.8.html)/[poweroff](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/poweroff.8.html):

```
poweroff
```

To [reboot](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/reboot.8.html):

```
reboot
```

Comment: `Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.` from ssh

Answer (score 21):

Use

```
sudo shutdown -h (time) (message)
```

This will [shutdown](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/shutdown.8.html) your computer and halt it. That is what the `-h` is for. Then, in the time area you can choose the shutdown delay (in minutes) and if you want you can send a broadcast message in the message area (like goodbye, or I'm shutting the thing down :P).

To restart the computer, type

```
sudo shutdown -r (time) (message)
```

Now, instead of shutting it down and halting it, you will restart your computer once it's shutdown. :)

Comment: What do mean by, "This will shutdown your computer and halt it. That is what the -h"? What is the difference if we only use "shutdown" or "poweroff" command? What is so special about "halt"!?