# how can I shutdown from the command line using lightdm?

Tags: command-line, python, lightdm, logout, openbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I restart /shutdown from a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187071/how-do-i-restart-shutdown-from-a-terminal)

In gdm I could use

```
 os.system("gdm-control --reboot && openbox --exit")
```

In a Python script.

What would the command be for lightdm?

Comment: if you just want to shutdown the system from command line you can use `sudo shutdown -h 0`. Does that not work in you case?

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the manpages and couldn't find anything in lightdm that would allow you to shtudown the computer. You could use dbus.

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
bus_object = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.Hal", "/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer")
bus_object.Shutdown(dbus_interface="org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement")
```

Which is [explained here](http://blog.sandipb.net/2010/11/02/restartshutdown-your-linux-machine-using-dbus/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it from terminal by

```
sudo shutdown -h now // or you can schedule it by giving time to shutdown
```

Or you can use

```
sudo halt
```