# Won't Shut Down?

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and when I select the shutdown option from the top-right corners drop down, instead of giving me an option to shutdown or hibernate, it only lets me lock and log out. I haven't made any major installations or changes to anything recently that could have messed that up.

The output of `gnome-session-quit --power-off` is

```
** (gnome-session-quit:2707): WARNING **: Failed to call Shutdown: Logout has been locked down
```

Comment: Have you installed a dock?

Comment: whats happening if you do it from terminal ? And whats the output `gnome-session-quit --power-off ` and after executing this command it will debug in terminal and provide us the output.

Comment: @Nuwan not sure what a dock is, so I assume not.

Comment: @Raja the output has been added to the question. Thank you!

Comment: which shutdown and what is the permission given to shutdown binary.

Comment: @Raja I'm not sure I understand your question... Can you explain what you are wanting to know?

Comment: @James I meant a thing like [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/04/you-choose-the-best-dock-for-ubuntu-poll). Sorry for not explaining it.  I asked about it because of [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112) bug.

Comment: @Nuwan I see. I have not installed any docks.

Comment: I m sorry, I mean in terminal type  which shutdown and provide us the output and check permissions given to that binary.

Comment: @Raja How do I do that? I haven't used Bash in a long time...

Comment: open your terminal and type "which shutdown"  and try to execute shutdown command from terminal http://askubuntu.com/questions/187071/how-do-i-shut-down-or-reboot-from-a-terminal

Comment: So that worked.  But I still can't shutdown the way I'm supposed to be able to.