# Automatic graceful shutdown via IPMI

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, remote

For my remote box, when I issue a graceful shutdown via IPMI, Ubuntu gives a pop-up on its local display asking what I would like to do.

I would like it to automatically shutdown without asking. Where do I configure that? Thanks!

Note: I am using desktop, not server.

Comment: Could you ssh into the remote box and enter `sudo poweroff`? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/187071/how-do-i-shut-down-or-reboot-from-a-terminal

Comment: I suppose I could. I have the IPMI app on my phone, and I would like to use that as it is very quick, convenient, and I am used to that.