# Difference between rebooting using terminal vs GUI

Tags: boot, kernel, shutdown, gui, reboot

Recently, I had a kernel panic and had to do a hard shutdown. On the next boot, I updated Ubuntu 14.04 using 
`sudo apt-get update` .

Following that I rebooted the system using `sudo reboot` as described in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187071/how-do-i-shut-down-or-reboot-from-a-terminal). Generally, I [reboot/restart](https://superuser.com/questions/652154/what-is-the-main-difference-between-reboot-and-restart-of-a-machine) using the GUI - clicking the shutdown button and choosing reboot/restart. Now I have been waiting for last 15 minutes and Ubuntu is still booting.

That makes me wonder **if there is a difference between rebooting using the terminal vs rebooting using the GUI**. My next question is **should(can) I interrupt Ubuntu if it has been trying to reboot for a long time?** If yes, then how (kindly mention all the required steps)?

Helpful links - [Is there a difference between reboot, init0, etc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64280/what-is-the-difference-between-reboot-init-6-and-shutdown-r-now)

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` won't upgrade you to 14.04. There's no difference between reboot and shutdown, except for the final action. The system may take a little longer to boot after an upgrade, do to housekeeping issues, but 15 minutes is way too long. Try hitting the `Esc` key and see if it brings you to a text screen where you can determine what it's doing.

Comment: I didn't upgrade and didn't intend to. My question is concerned about rebooting with terminal vs GUI.

Comment: But your first sentence says " I updated Ubuntu 14.04 using sudo apt-get update" and I was letting you know that command doesn't update Ubuntu, it just updates software databases. And reboot does a `shutdown -r` and shutdown does a `shutdown -h` so they're basically the same, as I said. Shutdown/reboot in GUI vs cli is no different. Did you try the `Esc` key to see where shutdown/reboot is hanging?

Comment: Thanks for the info! I hadn't plugged in my laptop so it simply turned off by itself even though I didn't want that to happen. Next time I booted it, it was absolutely fine. :D