# Screen stuck on Night Light Mode

Tags: display, redshift

The screen is perpetually pink, and it won't turn off. When I turn on night light, the color stays the same. I tried using redshift, and it doesn't work. Here's what I get when I type the command "redshift" into terminal:

```
Trying location provider `geoclue2'...
Using provider `geoclue2'.
Unable to start GeoClue client:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Geolocation disabled for UID 1000.
Unable to connect to GeoClue.
Unable to get location from provider.
```

Distressingly, the pink hue also appears when I boot to windows 10. Did Ubuntu just turn my screen pink because it stayed on in that mode for too long?

I'm on a lenovo laptop AMD-12 9700 Radeon **ubuntu 17.10**

lspci produces

```
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo
  (rev c9)
```

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the GUI (graphical user interface) power-off button solved a similar issue for me.

*Clarification*: That is, open the drop-down menu (upper right in Ubuntu 18.10 - I updated OS in the meantime) that contains wifi, screen dimming, battery status etc., and click the button that'll turn off your computer.

I guess either the screen dimming or the threat of immediate shutdown caused Ubuntu to re-evaluate its display decisions :-)

For me, the issue was that I had put my computer to sleep with night light on, and opened it again many hours later when night light should be off. The built-in display behaved as expected, but the external display was stuck with night light on. Flipping night light on & off didn't help, and mirroring displays didn't help, but threatening to turn the computer off did :-)
This is for a Thinkpad connected to a Dell display through a dock, Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: What's the "GUI power-off button"?

Comment: @jayarjo good question; I can see how that's not necessarily clear. Updating the answer in a minute!

Comment: Ehm... I know what GUI is, I just don't understand what you mean by GUI power-off button.

Comment: Dang! :-) Does the _clarification_ section help? I mean the shutdown/power-off button that you'd click with your mouse to turn off the computer, as opposed to shutting down from the terminal (see e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/187071/how-do-i-shut-down-or-reboot-from-a-terminal) ... because if I recall correctly, I only tried the GUI option, and have no knowledge of whether writing `shutdown` would have solved the problem.

Comment: Yeah, clear now. Convenient one! Thanks for clarification. As an alternative I found another option - I change the primary display, but revert as soon as I apply. That also seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Great to hear. Nice alternative! Please put it here as another answer; [comments are temporary](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment), answers are _forever_ :-)

Comment: Changing the primary display works best for me.  I had to apply the change though, reverting caused the issue to return.